# Lazy load an association in model

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I have a model that looks like the following in my Ember.js application:

```
MyApp.Game = DS.Model.extend({
  season_type:            DS.attr('string'),
  gamedate:               DS.attr('date'),
  home_team_name:         DS.attr('string'),
  visiting_team_name:     DS.attr('string'),
  gametime:               DS.attr('string'),
  home_team:              DS.belongsTo('team'),
  visiting_team:          DS.belongsTo('team'),
  home_team_pitcher:      DS.belongsTo('player'),
  visiting_team_pitcher:  DS.belongsTo('player'),
  home_players:           DS.hasMany('player'),
  visitor_players:        DS.hasMany('player')
});
```

This works just fine in controller "A". In another controller, let's call it controller "B", I'd ideally have two more attributes available like the following:

```
MyApp.Game = DS.Model.extend({
  season_type:            DS.attr('string'),
  gamedate:               DS.attr('date'),
  home_team_name:         DS.attr('string'),
  visiting_team_name:     DS.attr('string'),
  gametime:               DS.attr('string'),
  home_team:              DS.belongsTo('team'),
  visiting_team:          DS.belongsTo('team'),
  home_team_pitcher:      DS.belongsTo('player'),
  visiting_team_pitcher:  DS.belongsTo('player'),
  home_players:           DS.hasMany('player'),
  visitor_players:        DS.hasMany('player'),
  home_all_players:       DS.hasMany('player'),
  visitor_all_players:    DS.hasMany('player')
});
```

In this case, I have added `home_all_players` and `visitor_all_players`. There is a substantial amount of data to cross over the wire in those two attributes and I'd like to avoid using it for controller `A` which is customer facing. controller `B` on the other hand, is a management interface where an admin needs to have access to `home_all_players` and `visitor_all_players` so they can update an MLB team's lineup.

What's the cleanest way to handle this? I'm guessing on the server-side, where I use Ruby on Rails, I'll just have the serializer include `home_all_players` and `visitor_all_players` depending on what route is called. But the modeling on the Ember.js side stays the same so I'm not sure what the best way to solve this is.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it depends on your whole app flow and interactions where you need to have accessible a specific set of data, if you expect your users to experience any transition delay or specific UX.

As a general rule, my backend is in charge of providing the most convenient API to its client, so they can deliver the best UX, with that aim, you could use embedded data, sideloaded resources, new resource definition, etc...

I have done something similar on three different ways:

1) Sending a query param in order the server know how to serialize a resource.

```
store.find('game', {id: 1, extend:'admin'});
store.find('game', {extend:'admin'});
```

2) Based on your current user authentication, your server could know how the resource should be serialized.

```
//the server response would be different based on the auth header 
store.find('game', 1);
store.find('game');
```

3) Include a new resource which extends your resource.

```
MyApp.ExtendedGame = DS.Model.extend({
  game:                   DS.belongsTo('game'),
  home_all_players:       DS.hasMany('player'),
  visitor_all_players:    DS.hasMany('player')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO you need to extend your model.

```
App.Game = DS.Model.extend({
  ...
});

App.AdminGame = App.Game.extend({
  home_players:           DS.hasMany('player'),
  visitor_players:        DS.hasMany('player')
});
```

In this case you will have two controllers and related routes which are AdminGameController, GameController, GameRoute and AdminGameRoute.

You should get appropriate model from the server in the related route. Rails should return correct model based on controller.

Answer (score 0):

I use query params, and on the rails side the `ActiveModel::Serializer` determines whether to include fields or not, how many, sort order, etc. I'm not sure I would have thought to use a different controller on the client though.

I'm about to embark on a similar feature, more generally paginating large amounts of data. My thought for this right now is to extend `DS.ManyArray` and add some data in `meta` that includes a `loaded_count`, `total_count`, `offset`, etc., all of which can be returned by the API. The default might be to load 20 records, and then functions could be called to add more, or shift the window to another range, to keep memory under control. Or, via a query param, load 'em all.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relaying on single model you can create a base class with default properties and an inherited class with `home_all_players` and `visited_all_players` attributes.

This would be a better OO approach(IMHO)

For **Controller_A**

```
MyApp.Game = DS.Model.extend({
  season_type:            DS.attr('string'),
  gamedate:               DS.attr('date'),
  home_team_name:         DS.attr('string'),
  visiting_team_name:     DS.attr('string'),
  gametime:               DS.attr('string'),
  home_team:              DS.belongsTo('team'),
  visiting_team:          DS.belongsTo('team'),
  home_team_pitcher:      DS.belongsTo('player'),
  visiting_team_pitcher:  DS.belongsTo('player'),
  home_players:           DS.hasMany('player'),
  visitor_players:        DS.hasMany('player')
});
```

For **Controller_B**

```
MyApp.AdminGame = MyApp.Game.extend({
   home_all_players:       DS.hasMany('player'),
  visitor_all_players:    DS.hasMany('player')
});
```

The same applies for **Rails Model**. Change your current model like

```
class Game < ActiveModel::Serializer
  ## Your code ..

  def home_all_players
    nil
  end

  def visitor_all_players
    nil
  end

  ## Your code ..
end
```

And create a new model for Admin( extending Game) with those attributes

```
class AdminGame < Game
  def home_all_players
     self.home_all_players
  end

  def visitor_all_players
     self.visitor_all_players
  end
end
```

If you don't want to return nil in existing model exclude those attributes during json render. Refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397537/rails-model-to-hash-exclude-attributes)