# active model serializers rails json doesnt work inside another json object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, active-model-serializers

iam using active model serializers in my rails, this is my snippet

```
# GET /users
  def index
    @users = User.all
    render json: {data: @users, status: httpstatus[:getSuccess]}
    # render json: {data: @users, status: httpstatus[:getSuccess]}
  end
```

but its showing like this in postman

```
"data": [
{
  "id": 38,
  "name": "tyasa",
  "age": 21,
  "created_at": "2017-05-30T06:23:03.504Z",
  "updated_at": "2017-05-30T06:23:03.504Z"
},
{
  "id": 39,
  "name": "wahyu",
  "age": 21,
  "created_at": "2017-05-30T06:23:37.359Z",
  "updated_at": "2017-05-30T06:23:37.359Z"
},]
```

but its work when just render the @users

```
# GET /users
  def index
    @users = User.all
    render json: {data: @users, status: httpstatus[:getSuccess]}
    # render json: @users
  end
```

i just wanna delete created at and update at from the json.
How to solve this..
sory bad english

Comment: Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397537/rails-model-to-hash-exclude-attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just wanna delete created at and update at from the json.

You can use `except` option of [*`as_json`*](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json)

```
render json: {data: @users.as_json(:except => [:created_at, :updated_at]), status: httpstatus[:getSuccess]}
```

which should give you

```
"data": [
{
  "id": 38,
  "name": "tyasa",
  "age": 21
},
{
  "id": 39,
  "name": "wahyu",
  "age": 21
},]
```